# How To Remove Decimal Point in Crystal Report From Serial No Column

Tags: c#, sql

I want to print some reports in C# incoming Data from SQL SERVER. I have a serial no Column in this report Which also shows Decimal Values with serial no
like this.
         1.00
         2.00
         3.00
i want to remove these decimal points so how i can?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a number, simply use the formatting toolbar to remove decimals.

If this is a number converted to text (perhaps due to concatenating to some other text), explicitly control the number of decimals using ToText() function:

```
ToText({serialNumber}, 0, "")
```

The second (0) argument specifies no decimals.

The third ("") argument specifies no thousand separator.